# Select-String - find a string that spans multiple lines

Tags: powershell

I am trying to read lines in a file and search for a pattern that spans two lines. Looking at the file in notepad++ I see a LF char in the file.

Example log.txt:

```
I want to find this

value here: OK
```

My simple code does not work and returns nothing:

```
select-string -Path "log.txt" -Pattern "find this\n*value here: OK"
```

I have tried many combos of various things here including `.+` and `\r` that I found posted on various threads. I can get the first line by using:

```
select-string -Path "log.txt" -Pattern "find this\n*"
```

Result of above is: `I want to find this`

Adding anything more to the line above results in nothing being returned. Any ideas how to do this using select-string? I was trying to avoid using get content due to the potential size of the files I am working with.

Comment: `n and \n both work. I have been trying multi and single modes and still don't seem to get it to work.

Comment: How do you know where "I want to find this is" is it always going to be the previous populated line? So there could be zero or more empty lines before it but you want that previous one

Answer (score 4):

So I think I understand your question. If you have a file that has a line that you want to key off of then the next line is the line that you want to look at:

```
(Select-String -Path "Log.txt" -Pattern "find this" -Context 1).Context.PostContext
```

I wasn't sure if that carriage return was an artifact of your formatting or not. If it is not then this would work better:

```
(Select-String -Path "Log.txt" -Pattern "find this" -Context 2).Context.PostContext[1]
```

Here is a way to do it if you don't know how many lines will be between the two bits:

```
$file = Get-Content 'Log.txt' -Raw
$file -match '(?smi)I want to find this.*(value here: OK)'
$matches[1]
```

Comment: I think this way should work, but I have a bit of reservation counting on the fact the two lines will show up together.  The entire string will show up together, but parts may show up by themselves.

Comment: In that case you should use a multi line regex.

Answer (score 0):

Since you might want a multi line regex solution you need to read in the text file as one string.

Using the test file:

```
Stfuf
Bagel
I want to find this

value here: OK
Things
```

I was able to get the result using a simple matching pattern that satisfies your example text.

```
(Get-Content -Raw c:\temp\test.txt | Select-String -Pattern "([\w ]+)\s*value here: OK").Matches.Groups[1].Value
```

<sup>[regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/RvWzuL/1/)</sup>

Basically gets the text preceding invariant spaces, including newlines and the static text "value here: OK". Could be made better with positive look aheads but this seems to work fine.

Comment: Shouldn't the following work since it should span multiple lines? $regex = [regex] '(?m)I want to find this\n*value here:  OK'   It does not work, nor does many other combos of this I have tried. Your example above gives me null array error. I eliminated get-content though so maybe have syntax issue on my end.